# Two errors "Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last)" and "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Error binding parameter 1: type 'method' "

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, pycharm, sublimetext3

```
import sqlite3, hashlib
from tkinter import \*

     \#Database Code
    with sqlite3.connect("password_vault.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS masterpassword(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    password TEXT NOT NULL);
   """)
window = Tk()

window.title("Password Vault")

def firstScreen():
window.geometry("250x175")

lbl = Label(window, text="Create Master Password")
lbl.config(anchor=CENTER)
lbl.pack()

txt = Entry(window, width=20)
txt.pack()
txt.focus()

lbl1 = Label(window, text="Re-Enter Password")
lbl1.pack()

txt1 = Entry(window, width=20)
txt1.pack()
txt1.focus()

lbl2 = Label(window)
lbl2.pack()

def savePassword():
   if txt.get() == txt1.get():
       hashedPassword = txt.get

       insert_password = """INSERT INTO masterpassword(password)
       VALUES(?)"""
       cursor.execute(insert_password, [(hashedPassword)])
       db.commit()

       passwordVault()
   else:
       lbl2.config(text="Passwords do not match")

btn = Button(window, text="Save", command=savePassword)
btn.pack(pady=10)

def loginScreen():
window.geometry("250x100")

lbl = Label(window, text="Enter Master Password")
lbl.config(anchor=CENTER)
lbl.pack()

txt = Entry(window, width=20)
txt.pack()
txt.focus()

lbl1 = Label(window)
lbl1.pack()

def getmasterPassword():
    checkHashedPassword = txt.get()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM masterpassword WHERE id = 1 password = ?", [(checkHashedPassword)])
    return cursor.fetchall()


def checkPassword():
    match = getmasterPassword()

    if match:
        passwordVault()
    else:
        txt.delete(0, 'end')
        lbl1.config(text="Wrong Password")

  btn = Button(window, text="Submit", command=checkPassword)
  btn.pack(pady=10)

def passwordVault():
for widget in window.winfo_children():
widget.destroy()
window.geometry("700x350")

lbl = Label(window, text="Password Vault")
lbl.config(anchor=CENTER)
lbl.pack()

cursor.execute("SELECT \* FROM masterpassword")
if cursor.fetchall():
loginScreen()
else:
firstScreen()
window.mainloop()
```

In this code I had these two errors

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\\Users\\s###\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\tkinter\__init_\_.py", line 1948, in __call__     return self.func(\*args)
```

and

```
File "C:\\Users\\s###\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject8\\main.py", line 46, in savePassword
cursor.execute(insert_password, \[(hashedPassword)\])
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Error binding parameter 1: type 'method' is not supported
```

I cant find the root of these two problems.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of datatype mismatch. The table column `password` is clearly `nvarchar` which expects string values. So, on my machine I did the following to your `savePassword` function and the exception went away.

```
def savePassword():
   if txt.get() == txt1.get():
       hashedPassword = txt.get()
       with sqlite3.connect("password_vault.db") as db:
           cursor = db.cursor()
           insert_password = """INSERT INTO masterpassword(password)
           VALUES(?)"""
           cursor.execute(insert_password, (str(hashedPassword),))
           db.commit()

       passwordVault()
   else:
       lbl2.config(text="Passwords do not match")
```

In addition,
The context manager makes the `cursor` variable local scoped. So I introduced new context manager to work with locally.

Does this help?

Comment: The exception may well have gone away, but did you check what your code saves in the database? I think you will find that the database will contain a 'password' like `<bound method Entry.get of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry>>`. Something tells me that won't be what the asker wants.

Comment: yeah, I have checked it now and you are right. The parenthesis are vanished.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```py
       hashedPassword = txt.get
```

You forgot to call the `.get()` method. Because of this, `hashedPassword` is set to the `get` method itself, not what this method returns, and you get an error attempting to save this method in the database.

Try replacing this line with:

```py
       hashedPassword = txt.get()
```